# Aquire subfolder name of Read-Host root folder

Tags: powershell

I need to create a script that asks the user to input a folder name\path `$File`. From that `$File` aquire a subfolder name e.g. `$File\docs\ref\$host`. Then copy `$host` to a new network share and create that folder name of `$host` and paste its contents in there.

The reason I can't just copy `$host` is because `$host` name changes as does `$File` but the subfolders inbetween the 2 are the same.
I hope that makes sense?

This is what I have:

```
$file = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is your folder?'
# This is where I'm stuck
$host = Read-Host $file\docs\ref\$host
Test-Path \\Hulk\note\$host
If false
MD \\Hulk\note\$host
Copy-Item –Path $file\docs\ref\$host\ -Destination \\Hulk\note\$host\ –Recurse
```

Comment: Where does the `$host` in `$file\docs\ref\$host` come from? And why are you using `Read-Host` on it? Also, `$host` is an [automatic variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) that contains information about the host process. You're not supposed to modify it.

Comment: `$file = Read-Host -Prompt 'What is your folder?'` will contain folder name not in $Host

Comment: Aah, i didn't realise that $host was a automatic variable

Comment: try my script below working for me

Answer (score 0):

Assume that \Hulk\note\ref is the target you can create folder on that directory based on input host and copy the same folder to anywhere try this

```
    $location="\\Hulk\note\ref"
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic') | Out-Null  
     $folderName = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input folder name'
     $target = Join-Path $location $folderName 
     if ( -not (Test-Path '$target' -PathType Container) ) { new-item "\\Hulk\note\$foldername" -type directory }
Copy-Item –Path \\path\$foldername -Destination \\where you need –Recurse
```